# Could I come over on "a Saturday" sometime?

Tags: indefinite-article

> Use **a** with the names of days of the week when **not referring to any particular day**. [Education First](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/indefinite-articles/)

What does "not referring to any particular day" mean?

the website provide the following example:

> Could I come over on **a Saturday** sometime?

Doesn't the above statement mean the **next Saturday **? which is "particular day"?

if it means any Saturday (not any particular day), shouldn't they use **Saturdays**?

> Could I come over on **Saturdays** sometime?

Comment: It defines it: names of days of the week. a Saturday or a Monday means: any day that is a Saturday or a Monday. And not: Could I come over [is specific] next Monday. Next Monday is next Monday. A Monday is some Monday (not a specific one); I come over to your house on Mondays [all the days that are Mondays]. Get it?

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I got it. it would be a useful answer.

Comment: The website explained this quite well, I think.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, it is useful website, but I misunderstand the example.

Comment: Which is why I explained it. Actually, I can "locate" the issue. They should have repeated it: when not referring to any particular day ***of the week***. :)

Comment: Lambie, you are using "day of the week" incorrectly. **a Saturday** does indeed refer to a particular day of the week, namely "Saturday"; it does not refer to a particular *week*, that is, to any Saturday in particular.

Comment: To be honest, "use a with the names of days of the week when not referring to any particular day" is a bit misleading, in my humble opinion. The problem is twofold. First, it confuses *particular* with *indefinite*. Obviously, *a something* can be and usually is a particular instance of that something, it's just that it's indefinite. A speaker who says *I was born on a Thursday* or *It's 10:00 in the morning on a Friday, and he has a football game that night* surely is thinking of a specific day. Second, it suggests that *They were married on Friday* is incorrect, while it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @TRomano It is my opinion that you will do anything to make what I am saying look incorrect: there are no dates here at all. There are only days of the week. Period. End of story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could I come over on a Saturday sometime? (any Saturday, not specified)
>
> Could I come over on Saturdays for my music lesson?  (general repeated thing)
>
> Could I come over next Saturday to see you?  (a specific Saturday)

Comment: I did not want my explanations underneath the sentences. Had I wanted them underneath, I would have put them there.

Answer (score 1):

It means "not referring to any particular *date*" (i.e. day in calendrical time).

P.S. **Saturdays** would refer to a *recurrent* situation.

> Would you like to join our trainspotting club? We get together on
>   Saturdays.
>
> The open-air market takes place on Saturdays from May through August.

Comment: No, it specifically not referring to any particular date of the week: "Use a with the names of days of the week when not referring to any particular day." That means: A Saturday or A Sunday.

Comment: OP asks "What does 'not referring to any particular day' mean?  For the sake of clarity, and not to reuse the very phrase OP doesn't understand, "...when not referring to any particular *day*" should read "when not referring to any particular *date*". In other words, *which* Saturday is either not yet determined or is not relevant.  *I can go train-spotting with you, but it would have to be on **a Saturday**. Sunday is family-time and I work during the week.*

Comment: @Lambie: Your "date of the week" is not idiomatic.

Comment: "OP asks "What does 'not referring to any particular day' mean?" Answer: It means: "not referring to any particular DAY OF THE WEEK, as I explained in my answer. Your answer is a subset of mine and included in mine.

Comment: @Lambie: Your answer is fine.But I'm offering OP a rephrasing of what he found in the book (orig: "not referring to any particular day"), a rephrasing which is clearer than the phrase in the book: "day" should read "date". So my answer is not a subset of yours.  In your comments, as distinct from your answer, you are making errors, typos perhaps, but errors which could confuse a learner: "date of the week" is not idiomatic, and "not referring to any particular DAY OF THE WEEK" is just wrong. The days of the week are "Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, and Saturday".

Comment: her question is very clear. No, day should not read date at all.  You are missing the point altogether: there are 3 possibilities: 1) Can I come over on a Saturday 2) Can I come over Saturdays 3) Can I come over next Saturday. In her question, the book she is USING says: ***Use a*** with the ***names of days of the week*** when not referring to any particular day [of the week]. DAY OF THE WEEK is RIGHT for this question. Of course, ***date of the week*** is a mistake!

Comment: Sorry, you're using *day of the week* incorrectly.

Comment: No, I am not. Sunday is a day of the week. Can you come over on a Sunday. Refers to a day of the week. When you refer to a day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc. ) you use A, when it's not specific: This Monday, This Tueday, But can you come over on a Monday instead of a Tuesday. Or on any day of the week, that is not a Saturday or Sunday. Those two days of the week, I'm busy. And that is CORRECT USAGE.